# How can I customize the gnome panels in Ubuntu NetBook edition?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-netbook, panel, applet

I'm using Ubuntu Netbook edition, and I want to change the panel's layout (remove or move applets). But all applets are "locked" and I have no way to change that...

Is there a way to make them "unlocked" again, so I can play with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beginning of post should help you out: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-ubuntu-netbook.html

Comment: Wow I didn't know this, I use the DE on my Netbook.